# Facebook style popup window dialog using Angular2/Bootstrap/JQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, dialog

I'd like to create a facebook style notifications popup window dialog in my angular2-bootsptrap web application. The dialog, with a triangle on top pointing to the icon, that positions itself to the right of the screen. Are there any similar reusable components in Angular2/bootstrap or JQuery?

[image]

Comment: try to find from component libraries like primeng,materail2,kenedoUI. if you don't find any implement it your self. This is mostly UI stuff not angular specific.

Comment: @shilpa - please try some code with available component (if you use bootstrap or any other css framework it easy done), and then if you get any issue describe here... so we can help...